# Is it okay to refer to a class variable in a base class that only exists in inherited classes?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a number of classes that share the function `name` shown below. Is it okay to pull this into a base class that the other classes can inherit from? The `self.decoded_info` will only exist in the inherited classes.

I have tried it and it seems to work. Just wondering if it's a good idea or not?

```
class GenericTools:

    @property
    def name(self):
        c = None
        for i in self.decoded_info:
            if i[0] == "Name":
                c = i[1]
        return c
```

Comment: This is called ['Inheritance'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Inheritance_and_behavioral_subtyping) in Object Oriented Programming, and yes this is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, though it might be more appropriate to make it explicit:

```
class GenericTools:

    @property
    def name(self):
        c = None
        for i in self._get_decoded_info():
            if i[0] == "Name":
                c = i[1]
        return c 

   def _get_decoded_info(self):
       raise NotImplementedError("You must implement this method in subclasses")
```